# Multiple .htaccess auth sources

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess

I'm attempting to use LDAP authentication alongside regular .htpasswd authentication, i.e., a user may use **a valid LDAP user/pass** OR **one of the user/passes in .htaccess**.

The LDAP login is working fine, however I can't seem to get the .htaccess working alongside.

```
<Files test.html>
AuthName "Enter either your LDAP username or special username"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPUrl ldap://authurl.com/o=Personnel,dc=test
Require ldap-attribute objectClass=testClass
</Files>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Never needed to do this myself, but don't you need 'Require valid-user' for HTTP-Basic authentication to be accepted? Dunno how you'd OR that together with 'Require ldap-attribute [...]', but [this Apache manual page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html) seems to suggest that an implied OR occurs, so you might just be able to add 'Require valid-user' and get away with it.

Comment: Thanks! Adding 'Require valid-user' before </Files> was all that was needed :-)

Comment: Try a `Satisfy Any`.

Answer (score 2):

> AuthBasicProvider file

I never put it, and works anyway. Try deleting.
Let only AuthBasicProvider for LDAP.

I say this because i try use twice htaccess at time and "Internal 500 error" comes on when I repeat AuthUserFile.